# What element to use for the reverse of <abbr>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is there a HTML element that I can use to signify "this is what an acronym means", in cases where I want the full meaning displayed in the text rather than in a tooltip on an `<abbr>` element.

For example, I want to write down the definition of "CSS", and I put

```
<dt>CSS</dt>
<dd>Short for <mark>Cascading Style Sheets</mark>. This is the name of
    the language that stylesheets are written in.</dd>
```

What element can I use where I now abused `mark`?

PS you may contemplate answering to use no markup at all, but I want to make the name stand out in italics, so I do need something!

Comment: What about `<em></em>`?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans No, I don't mean emphasis; that would have a different meaning! For instance, when I run the page through a speech synthesizer, I don't want the speaker to raise its voice as if the phrase was more important.

Comment: What's wrong with `mark` or simply `span` or actual `i`?

Comment: @dfsq: `mark` is like using a highlighter to highlight the text. You wouldn't highlight the text in this context.

Comment: @dfsq `mark` has a different meaning again; plus I would have to reset the style properties that `mark` has by default. `span` would do, but I'm hoping for something more semantic. Then there's `i`, but that one has been abused so much in the past decades, and it's even being abused right now (for displaying icons), that I really don't want to punish it any further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTML doesn't have a dedicated element that represents the expanded form of an abbreviation.

This example from [the HTML5 spec on `abbr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-abbr-element) seems pretty close to your use case, except the abbreviation appears after the expansion in a paragraph, not in a `dd` element following a `dt` containing the abbreviation. The example demonstrates using a `dfn` element to mark up the expansion:

```
<p>The <dfn id=whatwg>Web Hypertext Application Technology
Working Group</dfn> (<abbr
title="Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group">WHATWG</abbr>)
is a loose unofficial collaboration of Web browser manufacturers and
interested parties who wish to develop new technologies designed to
allow authors to write and deploy Applications over the World Wide
Web.</p>
```

Based on the [description of `dfn`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element), which says (emphasis mine):

> The `dfn` element represents the defining instance of a term. The paragraph, **description list group**, or section that is the nearest ancestor of the `dfn` element must also contain the definition(s) for the term given by the `dfn` element.

you should be able to mark up your content similarly:

```
<dt><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dt>
<dd>Short for <dfn>Cascading Style Sheets</dfn>. This is the name of
    the language that stylesheets are written in.</dd>
```

However, I'm not sure if it's appropriate for a `dfn` to appear in a `dd` rather than its associated `dt`, even within the same `dl`. If this bothers you, the next closest alternative without having to resort to a `span`, is [`i`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element):

```
<dt><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></dt>
<dd>Short for <i>Cascading Style Sheets</i>. This is the name of
    the language that stylesheets are written in.</dd>
```

(and I'd probably add the `dfn` as a child of the `dt` and parent of the `abbr` instead as well)

Comment: Good one; I may end up using that. It's a pity though that `dfn` doesn't have an attribute `for` (like labels). The page does say that `title` is used in that way, but the title is still also a tooltip. Oh well.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Indeed, that's a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Either use

```
<i></i> or </em></em>
```

or use a span with a data-attribute tag, e.g.

```
<dt>CSS</dt>
<dd>Short for <span data-acronym>Cascading Style Sheets</mark>. This...</dd>
```

or

```
<dt>CSS</dt>
<dd>Short for <span data-acronym="CSS">Cascading Style Sheets</mark>. This..</dd>
```

If this is for acronyms you could also remove the "Short for" and just have

```
<dt>CSS</dt>
<dd>Cascading Style Sheets</dd>
```

and then another entry

```
<dt>Cascading Style Sheets</dt>
<dd>The language format that web stylesheets are written in.</dd>
```

Comment: It's not _just_ for a list of acronyms. This is an issue everywhere that I want to use the full name, and I want the markup to show that this is the full name.

Comment: Do `<dt>` and `<dd>` need to be within a `<dl>` (definition list)?

Comment: @William Turrell: They do - I'm assuming the dl is omitted for the sake of brevity.